# CSRF token from POST incorrect when running 2 Django containers in the same Docker host

Tags: python, django, docker-compose

I run two Django projects with two `docker-compose.yml` files, and both projects communicate with each other through a Docker network called `mynetwork`.

Everything works fine, however, when I log in the admin section of `project A` and try to log in `project B` with a different tab of my web browser, then user from project A get disconnected with this message:

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Reason given for failure:
    CSRF token from POST incorrect.
```

And vice versa, when I log in the admin section of project B and load a tab with the admin section of project A, user of project B is disconnected.

Both projects use custom `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

I tried to deactivate `CsrfViewMiddleware` middleware and play with the parameters below but I don't notice any change. How can I solve this issue ?

**Workaround**

A workaround seems to connect with different URLs for both projects, like `http://127.0.0.1:8001/admin/` and `http://localhost:8002/admin/`. However, I keep the question open because I need to run `project 3` and would love to find a more elegant solution fo this issue.

**settings.py**

Project A & B

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_structlog.middlewares.RequestMiddleware',
    'django_structlog.middlewares.CeleryMiddleware',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.User'

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://controller-django-1:8001/',
    'http://bookkeeper-django-1:8002/',
    'http://localhost:8001/',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8001/',
]

# SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'http')
# CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True
# CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

**docker-compose.yml**

Project A

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: controller_django
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    expose:
      - 8001
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
      - 25060:25060
    env_file:
      - controller/.env
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    name: mynetwork
```

Project B

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: bookkeeper_django
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8002
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    expose:
      - 8002
    ports:
      - 8002:8002
      - 25061:25061
    env_file:
      - bookkeeper/.env
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    name: mynetwork
```